# Average time for two different agents in sink block

Tags: anylogic

I am seeking help on measuring or getting average time for agents TypeA and TypeB individually in the sink block. I tried with timeMeasureStart and timeMeasureEnd but to no avail.

I used timeMeasureStart and timeMeasureEnd but could not get the average for the single types.

Answer (score 1):

just collect the information yourself, startTime variable in your agent and on the sink you do
totalTime=time()-startTime;

And you can add that to a statistics or histogram or dataset object that will be different for each agent type